# Calculate time difference between stored time and current time in php

Tags: php, sql

I am relatively new to php.
I have time saved in database as `datetime` with format `2014-08-09 15:56:28`

I want to get all rows that have time difference between this updated time and current time by less than 60 seconds.

I have been searching and found `TIMESTAMPDIFF` , it seemed complex. Anyone can help with an easy approach or better code using above command?

Comment: Better than what? You haven't provided any code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get time difference (in seconds) by this

```
$savedTime  = strtotime('2014-08-09 15:56:28');
$currentTime = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$differenceInSeconds = $currentTime - $savedTime;
echo $differenceInSeconds;
```

Now customize yourself.

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to use it in the sql query :

```
" SELECT pk_led
                FROM led 
                WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,date_led , NOW() ) < 60 "
```